# what are the difference between find and filter in jquery?

Tags: jquery

which method is best in the following code:

```
$('#navs li').find('.activenav').removeClass('activenav');
$('#navs li').filter('.activenav').removeClass('activenav');
```

Or can I use like this

```
$('#navs li').find('.activenav').filter('.activenav').removeClass('activenav');

or 

$('#navs li').filter('.activenav').find('.activenav').removeClass('activenav');
```

what happens if I do like this?

---

**update**

can I bind to both find and filter as my code needs to do find sometimes and needs to do filter sometimes

Comment: they are completly different, reading the DOC should help you to understand corresponding methods...

Answer (score 6):

The `find` method searches for matching elements ***beneath*** the current matched element.

The `filter` method searches for matching elements ***within*** the current set of matched elements.

Consider this HTML:

```
<div class="foo">
  <a class="foo">Bar</a>
</div>
```

And this jQuery:

```
$('div').filter('.foo').hide(); // hides the div with the class "foo"

$('div').find('.foo').hide(); // hides the child anchor with the class "foo"
```

Note that both result in hidden elements, but they target different ones.

Answer (score 1):

***`filter() – search through all the elements.`***

Reduce the set of matched elements to those that match the selector or pass the function's test

***`find() – search through all the child elements only.`***

Get the descendants of each element in the current set of matched elements, filtered by a selector.

Answer (score 0):

The first two lines are not equivalent.

`.find` looks for descendants of the current jQuery object, so the first line looks for all children of the `li` with that class.

`.filter` creates a new jQuery object that only contains those elements of the original object that match the selector, so the second line looks for all `li` that actually have that class themselves.

Given that, the first alternative is actually a no-op (the `.filter` won't remove any items from the set) but the second is incorrect, because it will first find any `li` with that class, and then only operate on any *children* of those `li` elements that *also* have that class.

Answer (score 0):

[`filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) searches through the jQuery array and looks for the selector you have chosen, [`find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find) searches all children with the selector you have chosen

**Update**

Yes you can use both find() and filter() like this `$('.myClass').find('.myChildClass').filter('.myFilterClass');`

Answer (score 0):

`filter` **filters** results from an element collection, whereas `find` **finds** results from an element (searching with the element as the parent).

An example on the SO code:

```
$("div").filter("#notify-container");
//Gives us a result, as we have a collection of `div` elements and **filter** the already made collection to only include `div`'s with the ID `notification-container`

$("div").find("#notify-container")
//Gives us no results as it tries to find `#notify-container` elements **inside** the `div` elements.
```